# gitignore a file being changed on server

Tags: git

I have a file

```
scripts/config.txt
```

I added this line to my `.gitignore` but when it is changed on the server and I pull, I see a conflict. And the problem is that it's already in my .gitignore so when I add and commit locally it's ignoring that file.

Why isn't gitignore ignoring remote changes too?

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete the resource from the repo using

```
git rm --cached
```

In this way it will be untracked.

Then you can add it again and it will be ignored.

**EDIT**

Also if you don't want to untrack the file, you can ignore it only locally, by adding it to the `.git/info/exclude` file, which has the same syntax of a `.gitignore` file.